# Python: How to Keep Alphanumeric English,Latin Characters in the regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want my regex to keep all alphanumeric English and Latin characters.

```
re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9-/().&\' ]+', '',"L'Oréal")
```

should persist with `L'Oréal`

Currently, it gives me `L'Oral`

Is there any Latin encoding that should be added?

Comment: Maybe you want to keep all letters and digits? `re.sub(r'[\W_]+', '', s)`. Your title and the regex with expected result in the question body are not in sync, since you seem to also keep some special chars. Try `re.sub(r"(?![-/().&'])[\W_]', '', s)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The solution is correct but I think it is syntactically incorrect. Its missing whitespace around bitwise or shift operator

Comment: I missed it when copy/pasting, so, `re.sub(r"(?![-/().&' ])[\W_]', '', s)` works, doesn't it? `re.sub(r"[^-/().&' \w]|_', '', s)` should also work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Idk, there was still some syntax error may be, however this one works: `re.sub('[^[\W_]-/().&\' ]+', '',"L'Oréal")`

Comment: No, that won't work (I am on a laptop, the closing quote was a single quote, I meant to write a double quote))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r"[^-/().&' \w]|_", "", s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZpCTFh/1)

The regex matches

- `[^-/().&' \w]` - a negated character class matching any char but a word char, `-`, `/`, `(`, `)`, `.`, `&`, `'` and space
- `|` - or
- `_` - an underscore (it is part of `\w`, thus, it should be added as an alternative).

Answer (score 3):

Why not add a Unicode range for all Latin characters to your regex?

```
r"[\u00C0-\u017F]"
```

Will match all your diacritically enhanced Unicode characters using Latin based alphabets. From there, just add the rest of your parameters of what you are looking for.

Comment: This didn't work for me: Exmaple: 'Porción de espacio'

Answer (score 0):

I think this one will solve your problem:

```
re.sub('[(?>\P{M}\p{M}*)+]', '',"L'Oréal")
```

And the result will be:

```
L'Oréal
```

Comment: this showme an error: re.error: bad escape \P at position 4